# C: How to redirect named pipe to stdin/out of child process

Tags: c, fifo

Basically I want to do in C (and without buffering) the same as this bash-script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat ./fifo_in | myprogram > ./fifo_out
```

In other words I want to exec "myprogram" and redirect its stdin and stdout to two pipes which have been created previously.

Another program is feeding data into fifo_in and reading out of fifo_out.

Of course it would be easy to just read from `./fifo_in`, buffer it in the parent and write to myprogram's stdin (and reverse for stdout and `./fifo_out`) but I think there is probably a way to let "myprogram" read/write directly from/to the fifos without buffering in the parent process.

Edit:

Eugen's answer seems to be the correct one, but I cannot get it to work.

I use this function on the C-side, which seems correct to me:

```
pid_t execpipes(const char *wd, const char *command, const char *pipename)
{
char pipename_in[FALK_NAMESIZE];
char pipename_out[FALK_NAMESIZE];
strcpy(pipename_in, FALKPATH);
strcat(pipename_in, "/");
strcat(pipename_in, FALK_FIFO_PATH);
strcat(pipename_in, "/");
strncat(pipename_in, pipename, FALK_NAMESIZE-2);
strcpy(pipename_out, pipename_in);
strcat(pipename_out, "R");

pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
{   //Error occured
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
}
if (pid == 0)
{
    chdir(wd);
    d("execpipes: pipename_in=\"%s\"\n", pipename_in);
    d("          pipename_out=\"%s\"\n", pipename_out);
    freopen(pipename_in,"r",stdin);
    freopen(pipename_out,"w",stdout);

    d("execpipes: command=\"%s\"\n", command);

    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *)NULL); // using execv is probably faster
    // Should never get here
    perror("execl");
    exit(1);
}
return pid;
}
```

I read and write the pipes from a PHP-script (only relevant part posted):

```
$pipe_in = fopen($fp.$pipename, "w");
$DEBUG .= "Write to pipe_in\n";
$ret = fwrite($pipe_in, $in);

$pipe_out = fopen($fp.$pipename.'R', "r");
$DEBUG .= "Read from pipe_out\n";
$atext = fread($pipe_out, 200000);  // Program hangs here
```

The program is started correctly, receives the input via `$pipe_in` correctly, processes the data correctly and (because it ran fine for many months) I assume it puts out the data correctly to stdout, but when I try to read from `$pipe_out`, it hangs. I know that the pipes themselves are set up correctly because if I don't open `$pipe_out`, the program does not get any input - which makes sense because there is no reader for `$pipe_out` and therefore the pipeline is not complete. So I can open `$pipe_out`, but I cannot read anything from it, which is quite strange.

Edit2:

Program works now, thanks guys - For some reason the first pipe has to be closed before you can read from the second pipe:

```
$pipe_in = fopen($fp.$pipename, "w");
$pipe_out = fopen($fp.$pipename.'R', "r");
$DEBUG .= "Write to pipe_in\n";
$ret = fwrite($pipe_in, $in);
fclose($pipe_in);

$DEBUG .= "Read from pipe_out\n";
$atext = fread($pipe_out, 200000);
fclose($pipe_out);

unlink($fp.$pipename);
unlink($fp.$pipename.'R');
```

Comment: Are you writing the source for `myprogram` or for some other program that "calls" `myprogram`?

Comment: Any reason to abuse `cat`?  Why not use: `myprogram < ./fifo_in > ./fifo_out`?

Comment: No reason to use cat, the bash script is just there to clarify what the C-program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a small wrapper for myprogram, that does

```
freopen("./fifo_in","r",stdin)
freopen("./fifo_out","w",stdout)
```

(Ofcourse not with constant paths!), then execve myprogram

Comment: Thanks, I've used this on the C-side (see Edit above), but the system hangs when trying to read from fifo_out.

Answer (score 0):

Korn shell supports coprocesses, which I think effectively does what you ask: read from a pipe and write to a pipe (which can be stdout and stdin of a C process)

```
http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/ksh/coprocesses.html
```

Comment: But how do you do that programatically from C?

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to use existing C code and wanted a shell wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
myprogram < ./fifo_in > ./fifo_out
```

?

As for getting rid of the buffering: Since your program directly reads/writes the pipes, the buffering shouldn't hurt you.

An important point is that the process which writes `fifo_in` should flush properly so you don't have to wait. The same goes for your output: As soon as a "work unit" is complete, flush your `stdout` which will make the data available to whoever reads the output pipe.

But you can't do anything in `myprogram` to make the writer of `fifo_in` flush its buffers.

**[EDIT]** To do this from C (without the help of a shell), use code like this:

```
- Put the names of the two pipes into local variables on the stack
- Call `fork()`. If that returns '0', then open the two fifos with `freopen()` [like Eugen suggested][1]
- Call `execve` to launch the real exec.
```

That's (in a nutshell) what the shell is doing when it runs commands. Make sure the parent process (the one where `fork()` returns a PID != 0) handles the signal `SIGCHLD`

Comment: That's how you'd do it from the shell.  But the OP is asking how he'd do this from inside his own process, using C.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking of a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)?  For example:

```
   mkfifo fifo_in
```

As a test stub for my_program.c, to read `fifo_in` via the buffered `stdin`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
   char buf[80];
   if (!freopen("./fifo_in", "r", stdin)) {
      perror("freopen");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   while (!ferror(stdin)) {
      while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
         fputs(buf, stdout);
      sleep(1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Then as a test for the writer, using the `bash` shell:

```
for x in {1..10}; do 
   echo $x 
   echo $x >> fifo_in 
   sleep 1 
done
```

Notes:

- I'd prefer to use unbuffered I/O.
- The writer, at least on my machine, blocks until there is a reader.
- The reader, in this sample, cannot tell when the writer is finished.